# click event not working on href in angular

Tags: angular, grid, angular-components

I have below code in .ts file

```
 columns: Array<GuiColumn> = [
    {
    {
      header: 'Company Guid',
      field: 'companyGuid',
      view: (value: string, obj: any) => { return `<a href="#" (click)="onClickDelegateAccess(${obj.companyGuid})">${obj.companyGuid}</a>`; },
      width: 330
    }];
```

Now this function is in .ts file as per below

```
onClickDelegateAccess(companyGuid: string) {
    alert("hi");
  }
```

But this function is not calling. Any idea on this..

Comment: The problem is that `view` returns a string. To the DOM the return value makes sense, angular however will not re-evaluate this string in the context of a template. Therefore the click will not have any effect.
Maybe if you elaborate on what you want to achieve and why you decided on this very solution we can offer a different approach.